# Java ScrollPane displays content but scroll disappears

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I want this `ImagePanel` class to display an image that is quite high, so I put it in a `JScrollPane`. Funny thing is, when I add the `ImagePanel` to a `JFrame` it does show the image, but the scroll bar is not there, and there is no way to scroll (not with the mouse either)

When I wrote it, it extended `JFrame` for easier excess because the part in my programm where I need it takes some time to reach and this class has many methods to draw on the picture. As a `JFrame` it worked as intended.

Another problem is, that I tried some things to ensure that the width is large enough to display the image, but neither `setSize(image.getWidth(), something)` , nor `setPreferedSize` did that. I case it is relevant I add the `ImagePanel` like this:

```
all.add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
all.add(contentbox, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

to a `JFrame`, so it should stretch, but for some reason that does not work. Contentbox contains `ContentPanes`, I did not deactivate the `LineWarp` so it should leave space to the `imagePanel` (this is not the reason why I can't see the scroll bar, I tried it on an empty `JFrame` as well with space at both sides^^)

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    JLabel imageContainer;
    ImageIcon icon;
    BufferedImage image;
    JScrollPane scroll;
    Graphics g;

    public ImagePanel (String cName) {
        super();

        File cFile = new File(cName);
        try {
            this.image = ImageIO.read(cFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        imageContainer = new JLabel(icon);

        scroll = new JScrollPane(imageContainer);

        add(scroll);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ImagePanel uses JPanel's default FlowLayout, and this may be the source of your problem, since FlowLayouts can allow components larger than they are without showing the entire component. To test this out, have your ImagePanel use a BorderLayout, and add your JLabel to it `BorderLayout.CENTER` so that it fills the ImagePanel. Alternatively, you could get rid of the ImagePanel altogether and just return the JScrollPane that holds your JLabel.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with a BorderLayout the scrollbar shows up. But even when I set the preferedSize the width is still to small. But I will try solving that tomorrow, it quite late by now. Thank you!

Comment: @Soronume: you're welcome. Consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That's the best way for us to fully understand your problem, I think.